# This is only one cell regardless of how many photos I have got from Flickr, and I can’t save these photos

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionviewcell

No matter how many photos I have gotten from Flickr, there is only one cell in the collectionView.

```
func loadPhotos(pageNumber: Int) {
    GetImageUrls.sharedInstance.getImageUrls(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!, pageNumber: pageNumber){(success, photosUrl, error) in
        if success {

            print("photosUrl number is \(photosUrl?.count) ")
            for url in photosUrl! {
                let photo = Album(location: self.tappedPinLocation!, imageUrl: url, context: self.stack.context)
                print("photo is \(photo)")
            }
            do {
                try self.stack.context.save()
                print("save url")
            } catch {
                print("Error saving the url")
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.albumCollection.reloadData()
            }

        } else {
            print("Error loading photos")
        }
    }
}
```

I can get photos from Flickr.

I get 9 photo urls, but there is only one photo.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("fr section number is \(fetchedResultsController.sections![section].numberOfObjects)")
    return fetchedResultsController.sections![section].numberOfObjects
}
```

The number of section is 1, too.

And, I can't save these photos. How can I fix these problems?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are saving the photo? What happens in this line `self.stack.context.save()`

Comment: Nothing, self.stack.context.save() didn't implement. The catch syntax run, and print "Error saving the url". Actually, if photosUrl is [ ], self.stack.context.save() can run. But when photosUrl has element, this line will fail

Comment: Can you post the method implementation of self.stack.context.save()?

Comment: Forgive me that I don't really understand what 'method implementation of self.stack.context.save()' means.
`let stack = CoreDataStack(modelName: "Model")!`
`let stack = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).stack`
`let context: NSManagedObjectContext`
`self.stack.context.save()`
And there is my project [link](https://github.com/MartinSnow/MyVirtualTourist.git)
It is on the branch 'FixCoredataError'